# 1,5-Pentanediol MS

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, spectroscopy, alcohols, mass-spectrometry

I'm having troubles assigning the signals m/z = 41 and 56 of the compound 1,5 pentanediol. I tried the basic fragmentations (McLafferty, loss of OH radical, etc.) but I can't figure the structure of these signals.

[image: 1,5-Pentanediol Mass Spectrum]

Thank you.

Comment: Worth noting that $\ce{C3H5+}$ has an $m/z$ of 41.039.  Not sure where 56 is coming from.  I'm not sure that $\ce{C3H5+}$ really _is_ the ion in this spectrum, but if it is, one way to get there would be by double dehydration of the alcohols, forming 1,4-pentadiene or an ion derived therefrom, followed by C-C bond breaking.  The MS spectrum of 1,4-pentadiene [_does_](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C591935&Mask=200#Mass-Spec) have a peak at 41, but admittedly it is not he main peak.

Comment: I found this paper https://doi.org/10.1002/oms.1210120113 that helped me a lot. Basically, there is an initial rearrangement and then the fragmentation occurs.